# Result not being displayed for machine learning prediction on the webpage

Tags: python, html, flask

I am working on Malicious Webpage Detection using logistic regression and have used a dataset from kaggle. Using flask and html i want to predict whether the url is good or bad.

this is the code snippet in app.py

```
if request.method=='POST':
        comment=request.form['comment']
        X_predict1=[comment]
        predict1 = vectorizer.transform(X_predict1)
        New_predict1 = logit.predict(predict1)
        new = New_predict1.tolist()
        new1 = " ".join(str(x) for x in new)
    return render_template('result.html',prediction=new1)
```

---

this code i have written in result.html

```
{% if prediction == 1%}

 <h2 style="color:red;">Bad</h2>
 {% elif prediction == 0%}
 <h2 style="color:blue;">Good</h2>
 {% endif %}
```

Why the results (Bad/Good) are not being displayed  for this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in `app.py`:

- `New_predict1.tolist()` returns a list.
- `" ".join(str(x) for x in new)` returns a concatenated string value.

In `result.html`:

- `prediction == 1` or `prediction == 0` compares the value of `prediction` to integer. But from `app.py` you are sending a concatenated string value. So, this `Bad` or `Good` will not be shown in template.
- You need to use String comparison like: `prediction == "some constant"`

I reproduced your scenario:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        comment=request.form.get('comment')
        X_predict1=[comment]
        # Do some operations
        #predict1 = vectorizer.transform(X_predict1)
        #New_predict1 = logit.predict(predict1)
        #new = New_predict1.tolist()
        #new1 = " ".join(str(x) for x in new)

        # Dummy list
        new = [1, 2, 3]
        # " ".join() returns a string
        new1 = " ".join(str(x) for x in new)
        return render_template('result.html', prediction=new1)
    return render_template('result.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`result.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        Comment:
        <input type="text" name="comment"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <h3>Prediction Result</h3>
    {% if prediction == 1 %}
    <h2 style="color:red;">Bad</h2>
    {% elif prediction == 0 %}
    <h2 style="color:blue;">Good</h2>
    {% else %}
    <h2 style="color:black;">{{prediction}}</h2>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: reproduced OP's scenario]

As you can see the `else` block is triggered in the template as both `if` and `elif` block is skipped.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now I am able to see a response as result but everytime 123 is being displayed. Can you please tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have set `new = [1, 2, 3]` in my code as dummy purpose. Please replace it with original code: `new = New_predict1.tolist()`.